# Eclipse Mars: Eclipse Error Reporting

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-mars

I'm using Eclipse Mars IDE (version 4.5.1, x86_64). All time it executes background task "Uploading usage statstics" (exactly "statstics", with 
orthographic mistake). This task never has been completed... I suggesting, it corresponds to Eclipse Error Reporting. How can it be disabled or completed the task?

Answer (score 1):

As a contributor to the [Eclipse Automated Error Reporting](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EPP/Logging) project, I can rule out that this job was scheduled by the Automated Error Reporting client. The only message remotely similar to “Uploading usage statstics” in our codebase is “Uploading error log entry”.